# Finding vertical displacement

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I am being asked to find the distance a shuttle travels upward after a given amount of time. I know that time passed is 79s, the rate of acceleration is 6.244 m/s^2, and the speed at 79s is 493.276 m/s. However I can't figure out what equation to use to find the altitude at that time, 79 s. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Hint: A change of perspective might help. Take $t=0$ to be the time at which you know the speed, and take $y=0$ to be the final position of the shuttle. Based upon kinematics, where was it $79$ seconds ago?

Answer (score 1):

Motion under constant acceleration is given by $\ddot{x}(t) = a.$  Integrating twice gives

$$x(t) = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{at^2}{2}.$$

If you set your initial height to $x_0 = 0$ and assume that $v_0 = 0$ as well then $x(79)$ follows easily.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the space shuttle is starting from rest at the launch pad at time $t=0$, correct?

I also assume the acceleration is constant.

**Speed after 79 s**

Velocity after a given time $t$ is related to the initial velocity and the acceleration through

$v = v_0 + a t$

where $v$ is the velocity at time $t$, $v_i$ is the initial velocity, $a$ the acceleration. If you plug in the units, you will see all terms have units $[m/s]$. That is always the first check. For more information see  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Uniform_acceleration) .

As $v_0=0$ we have
$v = a t = 3.244*79 = 493.3 \ m/s$
Note that we only have 4 significant digits in the acceleration so can only find the velocity to 4 significant digits.

**Displacement**

Now for the displacement, use the formula

$x = v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2$

also from Wikipedia. In your case it simplifies to $x =\frac{1}{2} a t^2$. As you can see, you don't need to know the velocity after 79s.